# Azure Powershell DSC or Ansible

Tags: ansible, azure, powershell, vmware

I wanted to find out what are you using for Desired State Configuration on your end. I am thinking to start introducing Azure Powershell DSC or Ansible for DSC of our on-prem environment and cloud environment. Would you have any recommendations? I am turning more towards Ansible but it would be nice to get to know other people opinion.

Answer (score 4):

**PowerShell Desired State Configuration:**

*Pro's*

- Great support for Microsoft Technologies (IIS, Exchange, SharePoint, etc.)

*Con's*

- OS and PowerShell Version requirements can become prohibitive.
- WinRM and the LCM can be flakey requiring fiddling around restarting services to get it working.
- Opensource Ecosystem isn't as strong.

**Ansible:**

*Pro's*

- Huge Open-source ecosystem around Ansible, with many ways of doing one task.
- Support for a wide range of technologies, enabling you to use Ansible YAML for vSphere, Azure, AWS, etc.
- Easy to hire people with Ansible experience.

*Con's*

- Poor support for the nitty-gritty of Microsoft Products, however, you can use the [win_dsc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_dsc.html) module to call DSC from Ansible.
- Ansible is becoming less important with the advent of Cloud, Kubernetes and Terraform.

Personally, I use DSC for my workstation and that's it now.  Previously I used it to bootstrap MongoDB and Redis clusters but eventually switched to Ansible because it meant throwing away the hard to maintain DSC and using open-source Ansible modules from Galaxy.

Comment: Generally agree but the point about Ansible being less important with the advent of Cloud is really debatable - Ansible is used a great deal on cloud in my experience and judging from ads for contract roles (I only do cloud-based Ansible projects and there's strong demand.)  Valid points on Kubernetes, there is less for Ansible to do but still useful (see the new [Ansible for Kubernetes](https://www.ansibleforkubernetes.com/) book), and Terraform (better choice to manage IaaS resources).